# Github action failed on aws-cdk dependency

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-cdk

we executed the same workflow an hour apart. The initial run was successful and then we received the following error in the subsequent execution:

> This CDK CLI is not compatible with the CDK library used by your
> application. Please upgrade the CLI to the latest version. (Cloud
> assembly schema version mismatch: Maximum schema version supported is
> 15.0.0, but found 16.0.0)

This error occurs in the cdk synth stage. As far as I can tell, we are installing aws-cdk@latest (2.5.0) and our requirements.txt is installing a number of packages. When I compared the dependencies between the two runs I found the following:

**Successful build:**
Collecting aws-cdk.cloud-assembly-schema==*1.138.2* 
Downloading aws_cdk.cloud_assembly_schema-*1.138.2*-py3-none-any.whl (150 kB)

**Failed build:**
Collecting aws-cdk.cloud-assembly-schema==*1.139.0* 
Downloading aws_cdk.cloud_assembly_schema-*1.139.0*-py3-none-any.whl (153 kB)

I'm assuming the "latest" version was picked up? However, how can I track this type of information? I have tried a number of searches include aws-cdk versions, aws-cdk 1.139.0 release date, etc... Perhaps, I don't understand the package versioning?

Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: We have encountered this issue and resolved it by locking the dependencies in cdk/requirements.txt as follows: `aws-cdk.core~=1.0,<1.139`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the new 1.139 release upgraded the schema version to 16.0.0, whereas 2.5.0 is still on 15.0.0. 16.0.0 in CDKv2 will be included in a future release. In the meantime, install the 1.139 version of the CLI, it will work.

A general way to solve this would be to upgrade your constructs to v2 to never have this mismatch.

[GitHub issue.](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/18370)

**UPDATE:** The latest CDK CLI 2.9.0 supports schema version 16.0.0.

Comment: npm i aws-cdk@^1.139.0

Comment: What does it mean to upgrade constructs to v2?

We ended up not having to make any change, I assume that the schema version for 2.5.0 must have been upgraded to 16.0.0.

Comment: I mean to use CDKv2 packages (2.9.0) instead of v1 (1.140).https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/migrating-v2.html

Comment: 2.5.0 doesn't support 16.0.0, but the pipeline is using the latest version of the CLI by default, which is 2.9.0, which is why your issue was fixed.